# How can I prevent timezone localization in a Query object in the ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, localization, timezone, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript (v3.28) to query hosted feature layers from a geodatabase. The API provides a Query class, in which the query itself and any configuration or parameters are defined, and a QueryTask class, that handles the actual execution of the query and returning the result set.

**My problem is that when I query date-time information from these layers using the Query and QueryTask classes, the times returned are being incorrectly assigned a timezone, and are also improperly localized.** This is likely a result of both how the data that I'm querying is being stored, and of assumptions that the Query class seems to be making about the data.

The layers that I am querying regularly hold date-time information. All of the date-time fields associated with these layers are stored in a DBMS with the data type `timestamp without timezone`. Because geometric information is included with each piece of data a timezone could be retroactively computed and applied, and I think that this would be a much better practice, but ultimately I'm not at liberty to make those kinds of changes at this time. My requirements specify that I should provide date-time information as a timestamp with no associated timezone.

When this date-time information is queried with the Query and QueryTask classes, however, it is returned with an incorrectly associated timezone, and as a result, an improper localization. Somewhere during the process of executing the query and returning the result set, an assumption seems to be made that a timestamp without a timezone should be associated with the timezone UTC±00:00. The result set is also localized, and as such the timestamp returned is temporally relative to the timezone UTC±00:00, which results in an incorrectly localized timestamp.

**What I'd really like is a way to use the Query object to specify that I'd like date-time information to be returned as the raw data stored in the database without any formatting, appended timezones, or localization.**

My actual solution has been to revert the localization by converting the timezone back from a localized zone to UTC±00:00, and then to just manually drop the timezone from the timestamp. This accomplishes the same thing, albeit with an additional date formatting function that wouldn't be necessary if the result set could just return the information exactly as it exists in the database.

Modifying the query such that it returns an accurate result set is preferred to using a function to process incorrectly returned dates. The first reason is performance. For larger queries, the need to spend time processing dates can be significant, and could be avoided entirely. The second reason is maintenance. It would be significantly easier to maintain a few configuration settings related to the API than to maintain a function that could need modifications if the API version is advanced and my project upgrades.

Comment: This will require someone familar with the ArcGIS API.  But browsing through the docs I found a little about this [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/inside_temporal.html).  That said, it's a bit unclear what you're doing with the result presently and what you'd like to do instead.  If you can show us an example in code, that would be useful.

Comment: You are correct. I'm relatively new to this technology and tend to lean on the documentation for support in this area. I can't post the specific proprietary code that I am working with, but I will attempt to create a minimal example of what I am currently doing and what I am trying to do, and then update the question with these details.

Comment: What is the data source you are querying? Is it a feature layer from an Arc SDE Geodatabase? I'm pretty sure that Arc SDE databases default to UTC for storing dates if you don't set a timezone. You can set the timezone for the service on the [rest server](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000015224).

Comment: I've updated the question, hopefully such that what I'm wanting and what I've already done is more clear.